# How far is the stronghold from your stronghold?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The stronghold seems to be really far away from my spawn point, and I end up losing all the 'eye of enders' I have. Any idea on how far a stronghold can be from a spawn point?(Since there can be just 3 in a world, I assume they can be **really** far away!)

Comment: Er, you should pick your eye of ender pearls back up.

Comment: I think you mean "from the spawn"

Comment: @avestar101 Eyes of ender have a 20% chance of breaking when you use them.

Comment: @Ragnagord Oh, is this a new feature? I don't recall it being there before.

Answer (score 3):

According to the wiki:

> All strongholds are located at random positions in a radius between 640 and 1152 blocks from the world's original spawn point, at 0/0 (but may extend further in or out of that area). The three strongholds are spawned at roughly equal angles from the center point of the world (that is, each stronghold is in the region of 120 degrees from the others, measured from the origin).

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stronghold#Spawning)